# How do I find what # is referencing in Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to evaluate a spreadsheet that someone else created and I find this formula in one cell

=[@['#Err Staff Email]]

I can't find where that is referencing in any of the worksheets. Any advice on how I can track this down?

Thanks!

Comment: that is a structured reference to a column in the table in which the formula is placed.  It references the item in the same row in that column in the same table.

Comment: So, when it kicks an error message, where is it retrieving that message from?

Comment: well that depends on the error.

Comment: I found it. Your comment was helpful